# Pyramid blogr tutorial can't see site at http://localhost:6543

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a vagrant machine running as my dev environment.

I am following the steps in this simple blog tutorial using pyramid(python) framework: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-blogr/en/latest/project_structure.html

Everything goes fine until I start the server. I get the message that the server is running

```
Starting subprocess with file monitor
Starting server in PID 2605.
Serving on http://localhost:6543
```

but going to the stated URL gives me a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

I think this has something to do with it running on a VM. So when I go to my local browser, it's looking for something on my Mac not my VM.

I tried changing the references to 127.0.0.1 in the development.ini to 0.0.0.0, but that did not fix.

Can anyone explain to me what's happening and how to resolve?

Comment: `localhost` means access only from computer which runs this code - in your example from VM. You can't access from external computers - even from host of this VM.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` should be accessible from other computers - but you can have firewalls or VM can be configured to block external connections. BTW: but then in web browser you have to use IP of this VM, not `localhost` and not `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It required two changes.

In the actual Vagrantfile I had to add the port mapping like below, and destroy, relaunch the vagrant machine.

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6543, host: 6543
```

And then, in my development.ini, I had to change the ip to use 0.0.0.0:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543
```